# Order results from one MySQL table by another, which is saving multiple values into the order field

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I'm trying to solve a MySQL problem, I have two tables:

1. `CATEGORIES` (COLUMNS: _id, _name)
2. `POSTS` (COLUMNS: _id, _category, _title, _text)

_category field in `POSTS` is `LONGTEXT` and can have multiple `CATEGORIES` _ID's separated only by , using implode(",") PHP function.

I try to list with PHP the 10 most popular categories, and to display in () the posts in them, but without luck.

I'm not very familar with MySQL, I only know how to use SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER LIMIT, INSERT & UPDATE so I will be very happy if someone can give me a good solution. I tried to use IN() but IN() needs the _category field of `POSTS` to be like this '1','2','3','4', now its 1,2,3,4 without the quotes, so if anyone know how I can transform this field into list without FIELD TYPE SET, I will be pretty happy.

Comment: What's your question?  You should consider another table in the database to relate posts to categories.  Then the most popular category query is much simpler, and can also query for what post a category is in, what posts are in a category, etc.

Comment: Please refactor your tables with a posts_categories table, and make life easier for yourself

Comment: Im pretty sure that something like this SELECT * FROM categories WHERE _id IN(SELECT _category FROM posts) with CONCAT_WS or God knows what will do the job. I cant touch the MySQL structure.

Comment: How would exactly would you determine the popularity then, event if you were to concatenate all _category fields from posts (google GROUP_CONCAT) into one string like 1,2,3,5,3,31,5 you would end up selecting all categories which have at least one post in them. Btw, I've actually tried this, and it does not work, because the 1,2,3.. is a string, and it converts to an integer when put into an IN statement and compared to _id (which is an integer), which means it takes just the first number (in this case 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM offer WHERE FIND_IN_SET(type._id, offer._type)) AS _count FROM type ORDER BY _count DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Works fine for now, its table type (columns: _id, _name) and offer (columns: .., .., _types,

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change your relation model to the following:

Table CATEGORIES with columns:

- `_id`
- `_name`

Table POSTS with columns:

- `_id`
- `_title`
- `_text`

Table POSSESS with columns:

- `post_id` (FOREIGN KEY)
- `category_id` (FOREIGN KEY)

A tuple in POSSESS relation (table) means the `post_id` is in the `category_id` category.

Comment: Isn't the _category field in POSTS unnecessary here?

Comment: @Pinetree Yes but, you have to remind that if your table POSSESS fail one day, you will be able to recover. It's just an int entry.

Answer (score 0):

the key word for this is "many-to-many" relations, if possible refactor your scheme like Mark Baker wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Using the model that Dyin suggested, you would then use something like this to list the top 10 categories by popularity (assuming that the more posts a category has, the more popular it is):

```
SELECT 
  c.*, # get all values for rows in categories
  count(p.post_id) AS post_count # here we are counting the posts for each category using a field alias for the count
FROM (
  categories AS c, # we are aliasing the tables also to shorten the typing a bit
  possess AS p     # you could also use aliases to join the same table multiple times
)
WHERE 
  c.id = p.category_id # link the categories and the possess tables
GROUP BY c.id # without this, the query would just count all posts, this way the result set is separated into groups by category
ORDER BY post_count DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Given what you said about your experience with SQL, this query might seem a bit over the top for now, but I think you could use as a starting point for learning more, as always, google is your friend. Start by researching how to link tables using foreign keys and joins.